# Rater analysis error dimensions of e1 and e2 do not match

Tags: match, raster, dimension

*Similar to [R stars error: dims do not match the length of object when evaluating proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72352195/r-stars-error-dims-do-not-match-the-length-of-object-when-evaluating-proxy), I want to compare land change of two raster of land use for year 2015 and 2022 , but I found this error :
*

**Error during wrapup: (first) dimensions of e1 and e2 do not match**

I try to fix with resample and retroject but don't works.someone have some issues or similar and have an idea how to solve this issues:The source of this scripts is https://youtu.be/kb2o7VbeURY

I try to fix with resample and retroject but don't works.

someone have some issues or similar and have an idea how to solve this issues:

The source of this scripts is https://youtu.be/kb2o7VbeURY

thank in advanced for any helps.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it match the expectations for this site. You need to include a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*. That is, the shortest possible R code that you can write to reproduce the problem, using data created by code, or that ships with R. That may be difficult for you, but, at the very least, you have to make an attempt. Do not include links to youtube and such.